# Initialise List based on a JPA query?

Tags: jsf, jpa

Good afternoon. I have a list of operators which I initialize as follows.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TiemposBean implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private OperariosFacade operariosFacade;

    private List<Operarios> operariosList;

    @PostConstruct
    public void inicializarBean() {
        operariosList = operariosFacade.findAll();
    }


    public List<Operarios> getOperariosList() {
        return operariosList;
    }

    public void setOperariosList(List<Operarios> operariosList) {
        this.operariosList = operariosList;
    }
}
```

The list is initialized normally and I use it without any problem but I want to initialize it based on the following database query.

```
 SELECT * FROM `operarios` WHERE `ESTADO_OPERARIO` = 1 AND `TIPO_ESTADO_OPERARIO` = 1;
```

In my JPQL query is as follows.

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Operarios.findByNombreLista", query = "SELECT o FROM Operarios o WHERE o.idEstadoOperario = :idEstadoOperario AND o.tipoEstadoOperario = :tipoEstadoOperario"),
```

And the method I built to invoke that query is as follows.

```
public void inicializarLista() {

    String namedQuery = "Operarios.findByNombreLista";
    Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
    parametros.put("idEstadoOperario", 1);
    parametros.put("tipoEstadoOperario", 1); 
    operariosList = operariosFacade.findByNamedQuery(namedQuery, parametros);
}
```

and there's modified my bean.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TiemposBean implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private OperariosFacade operariosFacade;

    private List<Operarios> operariosList;

    @PostConstruct
    public void inicializarBean() {
        operariosList = new ArrayList<>();
    }


    public List<Operarios> getOperariosList() {
        return operariosList;
    }

    public void setOperariosList(List<Operarios> operariosList) {
        this.operariosList = operariosList;
    }
}
```

and in my view I call it as follows

```
<p:outputLabel for="somOperario" value="Operario"/>
<p:selectOneMenu id="somOperario" value="#{tiemposBean.operarioSeleccionado}"                         
                 filter="true"
                 converter="operariosConverter">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione uno"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{tiemposBean.operariosList}"
                   var="operarioVar"
                   itemValue="#{operarioVar}"
                   itemLabel="#{operarioVar.nombre}"
                   />                 
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:message for="somOperario" id="msg_somOperario"/>
```

But I don't initialize it to me that I am doing wrong please I need your help. thanks

Comment: I'm sure you can narrow things down... Does the query run? Does it return things? Is `#{tiemposBean.operariosList}` called? Is it populated? In 99.9 percent of the cases, a question is not jsf AND jpa related at the same time (and certainly not mysql)... So please narrow things down

Comment: What is calling your inicializarLista method to initialize your list?

Comment: hi @Chris public void inicializarLista()

Comment: In your modified bean, `inicializarBean()` only instantiates an empty list. AS C.P.O's answer mentions, you need to populate the list.

Comment: The modified client code never asks to invoke the service method `inicializarLista()`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code that you posted, the "inicializarLista" method is not called. You have a managed bean with:

```
@PostConstruct
public void inicializarBean() {

     operariosList = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

But you are loading your list in:

```
public void inicializarLista()
```

Please, call the `inicializarLista()` inside `@PostConstruct` method:

```
@PostConstruct
public void inicializarBean() {
      //This step is not necessary any more!
      operariosList = new ArrayList<>();

      inicializarLista();
}
```